# how to loop through a JSON object with typescript Angular5 that returns a array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, angular

this is my json code that returns an array "Customers" that contains objects and arrays inside objets

This is my json cod:

```
{
  "Customers": [
    {
      "customerData": {
        "secondLastName": "Apale",
        "firstLastName": "Lara",
        "phoneNumber": "2711292033",
        "address": "Calle X avenida Y #100",
        "paymentCapacity": 18000,
        "gender": "Femenino",
        "name": "Yessica",
      },
      "orders": [
        {
          "amount": 34371,
          "term": "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z",
          "payment": 1423,
          "id": 12345678,
          "calculationDate": "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z",
          "products": [
            {
              "SKUNumber": 28005417,
              "quantity": 1,
              "SKULineDescription": "Computadoras",
              "SKUDescription": "Laptop HP",
              "SKULineId": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "customerData": {
        "secondLastName": "González",
        "firstLastName": "Pineda",
        "phoneNumber": "55678420",
        "address": "Calle 26 #4732 Col. Pradera",
        "paymentCapacity": 180,
        "gender": "Femenino",
        "name": "María",
      },
      "orders": [
        {
          "amount": 34371,
          "term": "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z",
          "payment": 1423,
          "id": 12678422,
          "calculationDate": "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z",
          "products": [
            {
              "SKUNumber": 28005417,
              "quantity": 1,
              "SKULineDescription": "Computadoras",
              "SKUDescription": "Laptop HP",
              "SKULineId": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

this is the declaration og my array: arrCustomers = new Array();
I try to loop through the json with foreach and i have error that says: undefined, this is my console
[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Comment: share your javascript code, not only the object.

Comment: I try print a element like that: console.log('Element: ' + this.objCustomers[0]); and loop through like that    for(let key of Array.from( this.arrCustomers.keys()) ) {
      console.log(key);
   }

Comment: You want to do? list all the properties of the object in depth? only the properties that contain an array? Anyway, your methods are `Object.keys`, `Array.reduce` and recursion. Explain it a little better so I can be of help.

Comment: Quiero acceder a un elemento específico "customerData" para obtener sus "pedidos" y "productos". I am new in typescript,

Comment: Make sure that the `this` in `this.objCustomers[0]` is exactly what you want it to be!

Comment: Give a simple example of the expected output, please.

Comment: @YessicaApaleLara. See the answer and let me know if you need any further help. Use @ symbol to tag any user.

Comment: I want to find a specific object within a array, I have declared my array "arrCustomers = new Array <Customer> ();" I have a method like this: findOrdersByCustomer (dataCustomer: CustomerData) {
   
     console.log ('Element:' + this.arrCustomers [0]); // in the console this is undefined

      this.arrCustomers.find (item => item.customerData === dataCustomer); // i want to show the orders by customer specific
   }

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were having trouble accessing elements of array and objects. If it is the case then may this help you.

Also, run those snippets who are commented.

You may access objects attribute in 2 ways, one is using dot(.) operator and another one is used in the example.

```js
var array = {
  "Customers": [
    {
      "customerData": {
        "secondLastName": "Apale",
        "firstLastName": "Lara",
        "phoneNumber": "2711292033",
        "address": "Calle X avenida Y #100",
        "paymentCapacity": 18000,
        "gender": "Femenino",
        "name": "Yessica",
      },
      "orders": [
        {
          "amount": 34371,
          "term": "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z",
          "payment": 1423,
          "id": 12345678,
          "calculationDate": "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z",
          "products": [
            {
              "SKUNumber": 28005417,
              "quantity": 1,
              "SKULineDescription": "Computadoras",
              "SKUDescription": "Laptop HP",
              "SKULineId": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "customerData": {
        "secondLastName": "González",
        "firstLastName": "Pineda",
        "phoneNumber": "55678420",
        "address": "Calle 26 #4732 Col. Pradera",
        "paymentCapacity": 180,
        "gender": "Femenino",
        "name": "María",
      },
      "orders": [
        {
          "amount": 34371,
          "term": "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z",
          "payment": 1423,
          "id": 12678422,
          "calculationDate": "2017-07-21T17:32:28Z",
          "products": [
            {
              "SKUNumber": 28005417,
              "quantity": 1,
              "SKULineDescription": "Computadoras",
              "SKUDescription": "Laptop HP",
              "SKULineId": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log("the whole array ==>",array);
//console.log("customers attribute ==>",array["Customers"]);
//console.log("first customerData ==>",array["Customers"][0]);
//console.log("first customerData's order ==>",array["Customers"][0]["orders"]);
//console.log("first customerData's all products ==>",array["Customers"][0]["orders"].map(i => i["products"]));
//console.log("All customerDatas", array["Customers"].map(i => i["customerData"]));
//console.log("All orders", array["Customers"].map(i => i["orders"]));
//console.log("All orders of all customers", array["Customers"].map(i => i["orders"]));
```

Comment: I want to find a specific object within a array, I have declared my array "arrCustomers = new Array <Customer> ();" I have a method like this: findOrdersByCustomer (dataCustomer: CustomerData) {
   
     console.log ('Element:' + this.arrCustomers [0]); // in the console this is undefined

      this.arrCustomers.find (item => item.customerData === dataCustomer); // i want to show the orders by customer specific
   }

Comment: @YessicaApaleLara, try, console.log ('Element:' , arrCustomers [0]); . I mean is try without **this**.

Comment: My arrCustomers is a global attribute

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for your problem?